# imagePickerController crashes when fetching photos from camera. From photo library works fine. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

In my `swift` app I'm allowing user to add a photo - either from camera or from photo library. He has a choice:

```
@IBAction func captureImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let imageFromSource = UIImagePickerController()
    imageFromSource.delegate = self
    imageFromSource.allowsEditing = false

    let alertController = UIAlertController(
        title: "What exactly do you want to do?",
        message: "Choose your action.",
        preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let selectPictureAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Choose image from gallery",
        style: .default) { (action) -> Void in

            imageFromSource.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            self.present(imageFromSource, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(selectPictureAction)

    let captureFromCamera = UIAlertAction(
    title: "Capture photo from camera",
    style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
        imageFromSource.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera   
        self.present(imageFromSource, animated: true, completion: nil)   
    }
    alertController.addAction(captureFromCamera)
}
```

and then I have a function:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
    let image             = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
    let data              = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    do
    {
        try data?.write(to: localPath!, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
    }
    catch
    {
        // Catch exception here and act accordingly

    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})

    imageView.image = image
    .
    .
    .
```

When user chooses image from gallery - everything works fine, but when user takes a photo - my app crashes on this line:

```
let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
```

with an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I need this imageUrl to display the image later on `imageView` - so how can I handle the camera output here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
> ```
>
> I need this imageUrl to display the image later on imageView - so how can I handle the camera output here?

You are wrong. You do not need it, and it makes no sense to ask for it, as this image, by definition, is not in the photo library — it has no reference URL.

The key you want in this situation is `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`.

(Indeed, in all probability you should *never* have been using `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` for anything, since you are given the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` in *both* cases. *That* is the image you are expected to use if your purpose is display in an image view.)

Comment: hmm, but later on I'm uploading this image to my webservice and I need a localpath there: `uploadRequest?.body = localPath!`. So how can I take the localPath from the image that comes from the camera?

Comment: I don't see why you need a path. An upload task requires _data_, and that is exactly what you get from a UIImage. — In any case, that is not what you asked! I answered the question you did ask, and if you try it, you will see that I answered correctly.

Comment: hmm, I need the `path` in here: `let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()    uploadRequest?.body = localPath!`, how can I replace it with data then?